# Alamofire: Issue with decimal type value response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am facing one issue while fetching data from server using Alamofire. Could anyone please help me out.

Here is my WS response:

```
{
    "id": "32321",
    "name": "product name",
    "brandName": "product brand name",
    "ratings": 4.6364,
    "totalReviews": 11,
}
```

And my model is

```
struct FALProductModel: Decodable, FALProductBasicInfo {

    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var brandName: String?
    let ratings: Double?
    let totalReviews: Int?
}
```

When I am fetching data using Alamofire `Alamofire.responseData`. `ratings` and `totalReviews` params are missing. 
I tried with `Alamofire.responseJson` to check the response but here also the same issue that json is not returning above two params.

I tried with a simple `URLSession` and here I am getting the proper response.

does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If the parameters are missing from the JSON, most likely the issue is in the request itself.

Comment: Try with to take ratings and  totalReviews String type.
let ratings: String?
let totalReviews: String?

Comment: Do you set parameters in your question? Maybe some info is missing there (not set at the correct place with Alamofire). Could you show the code of the Alamofire & the URLSession?

Comment: Make `ratings` and `totalReviews` from  `let` to `var`